# python: expanding a numpy array inside function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

I have a python function with the following signature:

```
def merge(segments, indexes):
```

where segments is a n-d numpy array and indexes is a one dimensional numpy array. Now, I want to call the following function:

```
np.where((segments == indexes[0]) | (segments == indexes[1]) | 
          ... segments == indexes[n])
```

However, I am not sure how I can generate this condition dynamically within the where() function call in python.

Comment: is `n` the length of indexes list?

Comment: No, it is dynamic, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have many `or` conditions, you can use `np.in1d()` to check if each element of `segments` exists in `indexes`:

```
np.where(np.in1d(segments, indexes).reshape(segments.shape))
```

Note that the output of `in1d()` is a flattened array, needing to be reshaped such that `where()` will return the correct indices.